# Python failing to create symlinks

Tags: python, windows, symlink

I'm trying to use python to make symbolic links. When I try to use `os.symlink` I get a WinError 5 "Access is denied" error, but if I try to create the same symlink using `mklink`, it works fine. (I'm running this as an administrator, and have the 'Create symbolic links' privilege.)

I then to use `subprocess.call` to call `mklink` directly with the proper arguments and such, and it runs without any errors, yet when it's finished the symlinks have not been created.

When I try to use Popen to run the command I get a 'system cannot find the file specified' error even though the directory is there.

This is on Windows Server 2008.

```
def createStudentFolders(studentList):
     grad_year = input("Please enter the year of graduation for the class of students being created (i.e. 2016): ")
     for student in studentList:

         student = student.replace(" ","") # Gets rid of the white space in the name
         studentPath = 'cpwd/{}'.format(student)

         try:
             os.mkdir(studentPath)
         except:
        pass



         print(studentPath)
         proc = Popen("icacls {} /inheritance:e /grant STUDENT\{}:(OI)(CI)F /T".format(studentPath, student))

         classFolder = "students/ClassOf{}".format(grad_year)

         try:
             os.mkdir(classFolder)
         except:
             pass



         os.symlink('{}/{}'.format(classFolder, student), studentPath, target_is_directory=True)


         print("Done")


def main():
   newStudentsLoc = "newStudents.txt"
   studentList = readStudentsToList(newStudentsLoc)
   createStudentFolders(studentList)

 main()
 input("Pausing")
```

File resides in Z:\

inside that are

```
cpwd\<student folders>
students\ClassOf<Year>\<symlinks to student folders go here>
```

I've tried using absolute paths as well with no luck.

Comment: From your description it seems your path formatting is incorrect. Without us having any code though, it is near impossible to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: It's `os.symlink(src, dst, True)`, not `os.symlink(dst, src, True)`. The order is the opposite of cmd's `mklink` command. Also, using `mklink` with `subprocess.Popen` requires the option `shell=True` because it's built into the cmd shell, i.e. the system almost certainly will not find mklink.exe.

Comment: I did do Shell=True when trying Popen but I'll see if swapping the src and dst works when I go in tomorrow.